# Where are extension attributes persisted?

Tags: magento2, extension-attributes

By following [the docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html#extension), I have somewhat successfully implemented an extension_attribute for order items, but they are not persisted and I can't find out how this is suposed to work.
My extension attribute is a simple `string` field that a want so set on the order item directly after placing an order. And I want to read it anytime so I can display it in the backend's order details table.

In summary, my question is: where are extension attributes persisted? Or what do I have to implement, if they are not automagically persisted?

Comment: I'm having the same question (I'm working with Quotes instead of Orders, but it should be similar).